# Why a local variable is not accessible in a function that is declared after the function definition and before it's call?

Tags: function, lua

I'm new to Lua. I noticed the following pattern in Lua. But I'm not understanding why it's happening.

Here, `a` is a global variable and it's accessible inside the `foo` function:

```lua
function foo()
  print(a)
end

a = 10

foo() -- 10
```

But if we declare `a` as local it's not any more accessible inside the function `foo`:

```lua
function foo()
  print(a)
end

local a = 10

foo() -- nil
```

Why the global variable is accessible inside the function while the local is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because global variables work differently: Local variables abide by lexical scoping. This means that variable visibility is intuitive: *The variable is visible only after it has been declared*; it is also visible in nested blocks (such as the function block) or other control flow statements (ifs or loops).

In

```lua
function foo()
  print(a)
end

local a = 10
```

`foo()` prints `nil` because the local variable `a` isn't visible yet; the function accesses the global variable `_G.a` at run time instead, which evaluates to `nil`. Setting the the global variable `a = 10` is equivalent to `_G.a = 10` or `_G["a"] = 10`. When foo is run, it indexes the global table using `_G["a"]` to find the value for the variable `a` which yields `10` as expected.

TL;DR: **Visibility of global variables depends on order of execution since global variables are just syntactic sugar for accessing a table under the hood; visiblity of local variables abides by lexical scoping - variables must be declared before use**

(actually `foo` indexes the upvalue `_ENV` which is `_G` by default if it was not assigned to, but for the sake of simplicity I'm using `_G` above)

To use a local variable, which is often recommended both for performance & readability reasons, simply declare it before the function:

```
local a
function foo() print(a) end
a = 10
foo()
```

local variables inherited by functions are called *upvalues* in Lua.